# How to copy data from differens spreadsheets and paste them on a Data Base one below the other? using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have different files with the same structure but diferent data. I'm getting all the data from the files but now I want to paste it on a new spreadsheet one below the other one, i mean, the data from file 1 and the data from file 2 below an the same with all the other files.

I have taken the data from the files using this code:

```
function leerDrive() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var data = [];

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Ow3KXDsf7eyEmbDrCUzkVFFC_-FNoEwA");
  var contents = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)

  var fileID, file;

  try {

    while (contents.hasNext()) {

      file = contents.next();
      fileID = file.getId();

      Logger.log(fileID)
      Logger.log(file)

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileID);
      var hojaCalc = ss.getSheetByName("ETS");
      var calc = hojaCalc.getRange("B14:V72").getValues();
      var conCalc = hojaCalc.getRange("E4").getValue();
      Logger.log(calc)

      for (var fila = 1; fila < calc.length; fila++) {
        var discCalc = calc[fila][0]
        var cuotaMcalc = calc[fila][6]
        var cuotaFcalc = calc[fila][8]
        

        Logger.log(discCalc)
        Logger.log(cuotaMcalc)
        Logger.log(cuotaFcalc)

        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("base intermedia");
              

      }  

      //return data;
    }

  }
  catch (error) {
    return;

  }
}
```

and also this code to get the data from a specific file and pasting it to the new spreadsheet:

```
function baseIntermedia() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("base intermedia");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rs3OujBExJKHY4b5IVT2oRsDimdzgVEjZNIEDxY8fm8")
  var hojaCalc = sheet.getSheetByName("ETS");
  var conCalc = hojaCalc.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var calc = hojaCalc.getRange("B14:V72").getValues();

  arregloDiscCalc = []
  arreglocuotaMcalc = []
  arreglocuotaFcalc = []

  for(var fila=0;fila<calc.length-1;fila++){
    var discCalc = calc[fila][0]
    var cuotaMcalc = calc[fila][6]
    var cuotaFcalc = calc[fila][8]

    
    Logger.log(discCalc)
    Logger.log(cuotaMcalc)
    Logger.log(cuotaFcalc)

    arregloDiscCalc.push([discCalc])
    arreglocuotaMcalc.push([cuotaMcalc])
    arreglocuotaFcalc.push([cuotaFcalc])

  }
  
 Logger.log(arregloDiscCalc) 
 ss.getRange(2,1,calc.length-1).setValue(conCalc)
 ss.getRange(2,2,calc.length-1).setValues(arregloDiscCalc)
 ss.getRange(2,3,calc.length-1).setValues(arreglocuotaMcalc)
 ss.getRange(2,4,calc.length-1).setValues(arreglocuotaFcalc)




}
```

but when I try to do it for all files using the while loop the code just stops on the first file, and it doesnt paste any data.

Can you please help me getting this solution??

Comment: `but when I try to do it for all files using the while loop the code just stops on the first file, and it doesnt paste any data.`Regarding `leerDrive()`:  1) no `setValue`, so no paste of data 2) `stops on first file`: worked OK for me. How many files do you expect. 3) Insert  `var counter = 0` at line 12, `counter = counter+1` at line 14, and substitute `Logger.log("counter:"+counter+", id: "+fileID+", file: "+file)` for lines 18-19. run the script and report back value for counter Vs your expected result.

Comment: `function baseIntermedia` - Why have you included this? What is the problem with this vs what is/was your expectation?

Comment: `function baseIntermedia` - It's another script. I used it to copy and paste the data of one file. and it works. but when I pasted inside the While loop it doesnt work, and doesnt get the data from every file on the folder. I expect the data for 39 different files.

Comment: `leerDrive()` - I get that there's no `setValue`, but even on the Execution record I just see one file's data.

Comment: 1) `function baseIntermedia` doesn't have a `while` loop. 2) `leerDrive()` - how many files ("Google Spreadsheets") are you expecting to see? cause it DOES work for multiple files.

Comment: baseIntermedia it’s a one file script I did for testing. It works only with one file.  When I try to put it inside the whole loop from leerDrive it just brings me the data from one file. I expect data for 39 different files.

Comment: Martin, there are two issues: 1) finding only one file; 2) not pasting data.  of these, "not pasting data" can be ignored for the time being; also ignore `function baseIntermedia` - it's a red herring. **Focus only on `function leerDrive()` - we need to understand why you only see one file**. So... did you run the troubleshooting code I suggested in the first comment? - `Insert var counter = 0`, etc If no, _please_ do so! If yes, then we can't help because we can't reproduce the problem.